# Can't switch to tracking tag badge progress

Tags: bug

On other sites I can choose to track tag badges instead of showing my next privileges.

[image: WritersBeta]

However the little cog to reach that setting is missing on IoT. Is this a private beta thing or a bug?

[image: IoTReputation]

---

Maybe it's intentional if I read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/268214/338924) correctly.

Comment: Maybe the reason is that there is no tags yet eligible for badges. I did face something similar in https://iot.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/362/cannot-select-what-ever-tag-for-next-tag-badge-selector The idea is that you can try to earn a badge on tag only if tag has over 100 questions overall by any users.

Answer (score 2):

It seems a early bird's problem:

You most probably did not have answers on any tag where the tag would have more than 100 answers. The site is young and there are only a few of options, where the criteria is met.

That `networking` tag in picture has now only 70 questions for example, and it needs some 30 more to be eligible for badge tracking.

When there are no badges to be tracked, menu is not visible.

So not a bug, but a feature.

Comment: btw, whole site has only 753 questions, it is quite uncommon to have 100 of that amount in one tag, so options are quite limited.