# Cannot select what ever tag for "Next tag badge" selector

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges

In my [profile](https://iot.stackexchange.com/users/1800/mico?tab=topactivity) I have to follow smartHome badge instead of for example networking badge, which is my top tag.

The selector does not give any other option, it has only that one value.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is said [on meta stackoverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335754/select-next-badge-tag-badge-not-showing), that tag must have at least 100 questions before a badge is able to be earned.

It appears that this site is such a young one that only smartHome (and maybe some few others I am not active in) have reached that level so that smartHome is the only one qualified to the selection.

By now, networking has only 70 questions and smarthome 135, so that seems the case.